# Selecting between span tags with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the annual fees for credit cards from citibank. Here is the url:

https://www.citi.com/credit-cards/compare-credit-cards/citi.action?ID=view-all-credit-cards

The html looks like this

```
<li class="annual-fee"><span data-id="resultsBullet3" class="">No Annual Fee</span></li>
```

This is what I have so far

```
library(rvest)
citiURL <- read_html('https://www.citi.com/credit-cards/compare-credit-cards/citi.action?ID=view-all-credit-cards')
citiCardName <- citiURL %>%
  html_nodes("[class=annual-fee]") %>%
  html_text()
```

I expect the output the be 'No Annual Fee', or at least something I can extract that from.
However, the R output is as follows:

```
[1] ""
```

For the rest of the 19 cards, the output is either "", or "Anual Fee: ".
Does anyone have any ideas of how to get the correct text?

Here is an example where the output is "Annual Fee: "

```
<li class="annual-fee">
    <span class="bold">Annual Fee:</span> 
    <span data-id="resultsBullet3" class="">
     "$"
        <span data-id="annualFee" class="">95</span> 
        "(Fee waived for the first 12 months)"
    </span>
</li>
```

Comment: you're not defining the `xpath` correctly, shouldn't it be `html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@class='annual-fee']")` ?

Comment: I think I did the css, and not the xpath. This yields the same thing. It either gives "" or "Annual fee: " but not the actual fee.

Comment: Two different spellings of "Annual"?

Comment: Looks like the text in the span tag you are looking for is rendered by javascript. So rvest won't be able to grab the html since it hasn't been created yet. You'll have to try something like headless browsing to trigger the js first before looking at the html. More here on that solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631511/scraping-javascript-website-in-r

Comment: Thanks! This is great! I think this is what is going on