# Updating clock scrape

Tags: python, r, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some data from a website. I can't seem to scrape the date (clock) on this page since (i think) it is continuously updated through a function and the xpath doesn't seem to work.

The page in question is:
http://www.tariffa.it/adsl/infostrada-easy-internet/
the xpath to the element I'm trying to scrape is:
//*[(@id = "clock")]

I'm trying to do this in R and Python and neither works. If you have some suggestion on how to get this data I'd be eternally grateful.

Thanks. (I'll post the code I'm using in R, I know it works since the rest of the data are being scraped fine)

```
url = "http://www.tariffa.it/adsl/infostrada-easy-internet/"
doc1 <- htmlParse(url)
exp_date <- xpathSApply(doc1, '//*[(@id = "clock")]', saveXML)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `//span[@id='clock']`?

Comment: Just tried, no luck... the output returned (as always) is: "<span id=\"clock\"/>"

Comment: I think you're going to have to use another library such as:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/27692016/499581. If you look at the output of `doc1` you'll see the html doesn't contain the time values, which are actually   coming from `$('#clock').countdown`...