# Using R to scraping some data from Webpage

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping

I was trying to get few information from below website using R

```
https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=ACC&illiquid=0&smeFlag=0&itpFlag=0
```

Basically I was trying to get information on 'Financial Result' from the Company information Tab in this website.

When I looked into the Source code of this website, it appears that the data of this Table (Financial Result) actually comes from a JavaScript called "`javascript:loadCompanySnapshot(glb_symbol);`", therefore that data is not directly available.

Is there any way in R to directly get that data onto R Workplace?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try something along these lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631511/scraping-javascript-website-in-r. Else, better yet, use moneycontrol data. I'm not sure but I think it is more accessible if you are able to come up with the stock codes (not that difficult IMO)

Comment: _"You may not conduct any systematic or automated data collection activities (including scraping, data mining, data extraction and data harvesting) on or in relation to our website without our express written consent."_

Comment: @hrbrmstr. Alright, understood. This clause, however, didnt put any restriction to read and download data, although may be manually. Therefore, still it may be good idea to leaning how to get data from such unstructured source(s) in general.